# C: Check for prime with various conditions

Tags: c, primes

For instance, where a number = 0 or 1, it outputs:

```
"It's neither prime nor composite" //Desired
"0/1 is a prime number."           //Not desired
```

For another instance, where a number is a negative number (e.g. -1):

```
"Error! You have entered a negative number." //Desired
"-1 is a prime number."                      //Not desired
```

> How do I go about excluding those not desired outputs?
>   I suspect the *for* loop causing those numbers(0,1,-1) to *return 1*, resulting in those outputs to appear. Any suggestions and hints would be great. Thanks!

Here's my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Checks if a positive number is a prime number.  */
int is_prime(int num) {
  /* Divisible by any integers from 2 to a num's square root */
  for (int j=2; j<=num/2; j++) {
    /* return "false" */
    if (num%2 == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  /* Otherwise, return "true" */
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  int number;

  printf("Enter a positive integer:\n");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  if (number == 0 || number == 1) {
    printf("It's neither prime nor composite.\n");
  } else if (number < 0) {
    printf("Error! You have entered a negative number.\n");
  }

  is_prime(number);

  if (is_prime(number) == 1) {
    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", number);
  } else if (is_prime(number) == 0) {
    printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", number);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have anything stopping the code from executing if you have an error condition. It will still continue. Also, you call `is_prime` *thrice*. One time disregarding the result, and that call you can remove. The second call in the condition you can keep, but then you need to change from an `else if` to a plain `else` to avoid the third call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line is also desired behavior.

Look at your code...

```
if (number == 0 || number == 1) {
    printf("It's neither prime nor composite.\n");
    return 0;
  } else if (number < 0) {
    printf("Error! You have entered a negative number.\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Because if you don't do this or something similar then  it calls `is_prime` which returns 1 and prints the second line.

For `0,1,-1` the `for` loop in `is_prime` method is not run. And in the last line of the method you `return 1`. As a result `printf` prints that it is prime.

#### Error in logic

In your prime detection code..you should use this `if (num%j == 0)`. otherwise it is an error.

```
int is_prime(int num) {
  /* Divisible by any integers from 2 to a num's square root */
  for (int j=2; j*j<=num; j++) {
    /* return "false" */
    if (num%j == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  /* Otherwise, return "true" */
  return 1;
}
```

#### Few things to look into :-

1. In your code you have unnecessariily called the `is_prime` method twice. One of them was not even considering the returned value.
2. Also sometimes you will have to call a method and whose result will decide which one you need to output. Then instead of `if-else` you can store the return value and then work on it.

> ```
> int retVal = func();
> if(retVal==1)
>    printf("..");
> else if( retVal==2)
>    printf("..something different..");
> else
>    printf("..something else..");
> ```

When it is just two values or two types you are returning you can do this

```
if(func()==2)
 // do this
else
 // do that
```

Comment: @MFM Notice the subtle difference between your code and @coderredoc 's posted answer is the `return 0` statement -- this causes the program to exit so you don't get extraneous prints.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know "return" could be used this way. Thank you, both, for your help as well as @coderredoc.

Comment: @MFM.: You should check the logic mentioned here.

Comment: @MFM.: Look I will modify the answer so that you can follow some good practices...Look into them later when you come in this question

Answer (score 1):

Just change `main` as follows:

```
int main() {
  int number;

  printf("Enter a positive integer:\n");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  if (number == 0 || number == 1) {
    printf("It's neither prime nor composite.\n");
  } else if (number < 0) {
    printf("Error! You have entered a negative number.\n");
  } else if (is_prime(number)) {
    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", number);
  } else {
    printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", number);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This way it doesn't call `is_prime` if one of the special cases is in effect.  I also removed some unnecessary calls to `is_prime` (the first call did nothing at all, and the last call was redundant).

Update:  I should point out that this post only addresses the problems in `main`.  When I posted this, I had not looked at `is_prime`.  See coderredoc's post for how to fix it.

Comment: I now understand that "is_prime" is being called for both of those special cases and hence the additional output. As for "is_prime" being a condition of the if-statement, the reason is that it returns 1 and so it'll be True. Correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Right, in C zero is false and non-zero is true.  Even better would be for `is_prime` to return `true` or `false` which you can get from `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: Much appreciated! Will look up on <stdbool.h> and hopefully use it in the future.